# How to use ConfirmButtonExtender conditionally in asp.net?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit

net web application project.

I'm using `ConfirmButtonExtender` for confirmation.
first I want to validate all the required fields than I want to show confirm message to the user. But I can see it every time. I want to use it conditional.

This is my Code.

```
<asp:Button ID="UpdatebuttonUpdaterID" runat="server" 
            Text="Update" CssClass="create_role_button_in"
            OnClick="UpdatebuttonUpdaterID_Click" ClientIDMode="Static"/>
<ajaxToolkit:ConfirmButtonExtender ID="ConfirmButtonExtender3" 
            runat="server" TargetControlID="UpdatebuttonUpdaterID"
            ConfirmOnFormSubmit="true" BehaviorID="updateBehavior" 
            ClientIDMode="Static" DisplayModalPopupID="ModalPopupExtender3"/>
<asp:ModalPopupExtender ID="ModalPopupExtender3" runat="server" 
                        TargetControlID="UpdatebuttonUpdaterID"
                        PopupControlID="Panel3" OkControlID="Button5" 
                        CancelControlID="Button6" ClientIDMode="Static" >
</asp:ModalPopupExtender>
<asp:Panel runat="server" ID="Panel3" Style="display: none; width: 200px; background-color: White; border-width: 2px; border-color: Black; border-style: solid; padding: 20px;">
    Do you want to send this Conversion Rate for Approval?<br />
    <asp:Button runat="server" ID="Button5" Text="OK" />
    <asp:Button runat="server" ID="Button6" Text="Cancel" />
</asp:Panel>
```

javascript code:

```
Sys.Application.add_load(wireEvents);

function wireEvents() {
    var behavior = $find("confirmBehavior");
    if (behavior != null) {

        behavior.add_showing(OnClientClickApprove);
    }

    var updateBehavior = $find("updateBehavior");
    if (updateBehavior != null) {
        updateBehavior.add_showing(OnClientClickUpdate);
    }
}

function OnClientClickUpdate() {

    if (some condition)
        return false;
}
```

So, If `OnClientClickUpdate` returns false, User should not see confirm message. 
If it returns true then only User should be able to see the confirm message on UI.

Comment: not a proper solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can assign a client click handler with your function in it. A little dirty, but ensures (in practice) your handler comes first in the chain and cancels further handlers:

```
<asp:Button ID="UpdatebuttonUpdaterID" runat="server"
            OnClientClick="return OnClientClickUpdate();"
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to rewrite the `OnClientClickUpdate` function like this:

```
function OnClientClickUpdate(sender, eventArgs) {

    if (some condition)
        eventArgs.set_cancel(true);
}
```